# How to obtain summary rows where each summary is dependent on another column?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, analytics, summary

**Oracle11g**

How to obtain summary rows where each pair of rows meet minimum sums?
When I specify `where total_lot > N` then I exclude rows I want to retain.

I want to answer this data question: What ids have KEYS with total lot sizes greater than 6 **AND** have LOCK with total lot sizes greater than 4?

```
with inventory_items as
(
  select 1 as item_id, 'KEYS' as code, '1020' as sub_code, 4 as lot_size from dual     union all
  select 1 as item_id, 'KEYS' as code, '2210' as sub_code, 4 as lot_size from dual  union all
  select 1 as item_id, 'LOCK' as code, '1610' as sub_code, 3 as lot_size from dual  union all
  select 1 as item_id, 'LOCK' as code, '1031' as sub_code, 2 as lot_size from dual  union all
  select 2 as item_id, 'KEYS' as code, '1020' as sub_code, 2 as lot_size from dual  union all
  select 2 as item_id, 'KEYS' as code, '2210' as sub_code, 1 as lot_size from dual  union all
  select 2 as item_id, 'LOCK' as code, '1610' as sub_code, 1 as lot_size from dual  union all
  select 2 as item_id, 'LOCK' as code, '1031' as sub_code, 3 as lot_size from dual  union all
  select 3 as item_id, 'KEYS' as code, '1031' as sub_code, 8 as lot_size from dual 
  )
  select distinct item_id, code, 
         sum(lot_size) over (partition by item_id, code) as total_lot
  from inventory_items
  order by item_id, code
```

**DESIRED RESULTS**

1. ID has LOCK and
2. ID has KEYS and
3. Total_lot for KEYS is > 6 and
4. Total_lot for LOCK is > 4

Output:

```
 ITEM_ID   CODE   TOTAL_LOT
 -----     -----  --------
 1         KEYS   8
 1         LOCK   5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution.

**Explanation**

Use Gordon's query to select all item_ids meeting the quantity requirements. This query returns ID=3 because total KEYS > 6.

```
select item_id, 
       code, 
       sum(lot_size) total_lot
from inventory_items 
group by item_id, code
having sum(lot_size) > (case 
                         when code = 'KEYS' then 6
                         when code = 'LOCK' then 4
                        end)
```

**Output**

```
ITEM_ID  CODE  TOTAL_LOT
------------------------
 1       KEYS  8
 1       LOCK  5
 3       KEYS  8
```

Now, you need to exclude ID=3 because your requirement is to include only those IDs having both KEYS and LOCK. That is, you want to return exactly two rows per item_id.  So take the previous query and add a column that counts the number of item_id.

```
select item_id,
       code,
       total_lot,
       count(*) over (partition by item_id) as item_count
from (
select item_id, 
       code, 
       sum(lot_size) total_lot
from inventory_items 
group by item_id, code
having sum(lot_size) > (case 
                         when code = 'KEYS' then 6
                         when code = 'LOCK' then 4
                        end)
 )
```

**Output**

```
ITEM_ID CODE  TOTAL_LOT ITEM_COUNT
------- ---- ---------- ----------
1       KEYS      8          2
1       LOCK      5          2
3       KEYS      8          1
```

This gives you a column to filter row counts, but to use 
it you need to nest once more.

```
select item_id, 
       code,
       total_lot
from (
 select item_id,
       code,
       total_lot,
       count(*) over (partition by item_id) as item_count
from (
select item_id, 
       code, 
       sum(lot_size) total_lot
from inventory_items 
group by item_id, code
having sum(lot_size) > (case 
                         when code = 'KEYS' then 6
                         when code = 'LOCK' then 4
                        end)
 ) 
) where item_count=2
```

**Output**

```
 ITEM_ID  CODE  TOTAL_LOT
 ------------------------
 1       KEYS  8
 1       LOCK  5
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
select item_id, code, sum(lot_size)
from inventory_items ii
group by item_id, code
having sum(lot_size) > (case when code = 'KEYS' then 6
                             when code = 'LOCK' then 4
                        end)
```

By the way, the query in your example code is a very cumbersome way of doing a `group by`.

In response to your comment, assuming you mean the *sum* of the lot sizes for the two:

```
select item_id, sum(lot_size)
from inventory_items ii
group by item_id
having sum(case when code = 'KEYS' then lot_size else 0 end) > 6 and
       sum(case when code = 'LOCK' then lot_size else 0 end) > 4
```

If you mean having just any lot size greater than a value, then use `max()` instead of `sum()` in the `having` clause.

The easiest way to include the code is to just join the original data back to this.  Here is one way to express it:

```
select *
from inventory_items ii
where ii.item_id in (select item_id, sum(lot_size)
                     from inventory_items ii
                      group by item_id
                      having sum(case when code = 'KEYS' then lot_size else 0 end) > 6 and
                             sum(case when code = 'LOCK' then lot_size else 0 end) > 4
                    )
```

Comment: Gordon, not quite. I'm wanting to answer: What ids have KEYS with total lot sizes greater than 6 AND have LOCK's with lot sizes greater than 4? Your suggestion includes id=3 but I don't want it b/c it doesn't have LOCKS.  Since you noted, how can I get aggregate sums by id without group by?

Comment: Gordon, thanks for responding. The second query, contains the correct summary of 13 which is sum of id=1 for lock and key, but I want to report the code as well. I don't get expected results when I include 'code' in the select and group by clauses. You've given me some ideas to consider though.